# Djongo fails to migrate contenttypes migrations

Tags: django, djongo

I am using djongo for MongoDB connection in my project. I have cleaned all previous migrations, deleted the sqlite database and made migrations for the app again. Here are all the migrations that need to be run

```sh
python3 manage.py showmigrations
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
admin_interface
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_add_related_modal
 [X] 0003_add_logo_color
 [X] 0004_rename_title_color
 [X] 0005_add_recent_actions_visible
 [X] 0006_bytes_to_str
 [X] 0007_add_favicon
 [X] 0008_change_related_modal_background_opacity_type
 [X] 0009_add_enviroment
 [X] 0010_add_localization
 [X] 0011_add_environment_options
 [X] 0012_update_verbose_names
 [X] 0013_add_related_modal_close_button
 [X] 0014_name_unique
 [X] 0015_add_language_chooser_active
 [X] 0016_add_language_chooser_display
 [X] 0017_change_list_filter_dropdown
 [X] 0018_theme_list_filter_sticky
 [X] 0019_add_form_sticky
app
 [X] 0001_initial
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
 [X] 0010_alter_group_name_max_length
 [X] 0011_update_proxy_permissions
 [X] 0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
```

It runs all migrations except the contenttypes migrations. Here is the output from `python3 manage.py migrate`

```sh
Applying contenttypes.0001_initial...This version of djongo does not support "schema validation using CONSTRAINT" fully. Visit https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/support/
 OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial...This version of djongo does not support "NULL, NOT NULL column validation check" fully. Visit https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/support/
This version of djongo does not support "schema validation using KEY" fully. Visit https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/support/
This version of djongo does not support "schema validation using REFERENCES" fully. Visit https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/support/
 OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying admin_interface.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin_interface.0002_add_related_modal...This version of djongo does not support "schema validation using NOT NULL" fully. Visit https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/support/
This version of djongo does not support "COLUMN DROP DEFAULT " fully. Visit https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/support/
This version of djongo does not support "column type validation" fully. Visit https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/support/
 OK
  Applying admin_interface.0003_add_logo_color... OK
  Applying admin_interface.0004_rename_title_color... OK
  Applying admin_interface.0005_add_recent_actions_visible... OK
  Applying admin_interface.0006_bytes_to_str... OK
  Applying admin_interface.0007_add_favicon... OK
  Applying admin_interface.0008_change_related_modal_background_opacity_type...This version of djongo does not support "DROP CASCADE" fully. Visit https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/support/
 OK
  Applying admin_interface.0009_add_enviroment... OK
  Applying admin_interface.0010_add_localization... OK
  Applying admin_interface.0011_add_environment_options... OK
  Applying admin_interface.0012_update_verbose_names... OK
  Applying admin_interface.0013_add_related_modal_close_button... OK
  Applying admin_interface.0014_name_unique... OK
  Applying admin_interface.0015_add_language_chooser_active... OK
  Applying admin_interface.0016_add_language_chooser_display... OK
  Applying admin_interface.0017_change_list_filter_dropdown... OK
  Applying admin_interface.0018_theme_list_filter_sticky... OK
  Applying admin_interface.0019_add_form_sticky... OK
  Applying app.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name...This version of djongo does not support "COLUMN DROP NOT NULL " fully. Visit https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/support/
 OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying auth.0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 857, in parse
    return handler(self, statement)
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 933, in _select
    return SelectQuery(self.db, self.connection_properties, sm, self._params)
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 116, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args)
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 152, in parse
    self.where = WhereConverter(self, statement)
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/converters.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/converters.py", line 119, in parse
    self.op = WhereOp(
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/operators.py", line 475, in __init__
    self._statement2ops()
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/operators.py", line 438, in _statement2ops
    if prev_op.lhs is None:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lhs'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 51, in execute
    self.result = Query(
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 784, in __init__
    self._query = self.parse()
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 885, in parse
    raise exe from e
djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError: 

        Keyword: None
        Sub SQL: None
        FAILED SQL: SELECT "admin_interface_theme"."id", "admin_interface_theme"."name", "admin_interface_theme"."active", "admin_interface_theme"."title", "admin_interface_theme"."title_color", "admin_interface_theme"."title_visible", "admin_interface_theme"."logo", "admin_interface_theme"."logo_color", "admin_interface_theme"."logo_visible", "admin_interface_theme"."favicon", "admin_interface_theme"."env_name", "admin_interface_theme"."env_color", "admin_interface_theme"."env_visible_in_header", "admin_interface_theme"."env_visible_in_favicon", "admin_interface_theme"."language_chooser_active", "admin_interface_theme"."language_chooser_display", "admin_interface_theme"."css_header_background_color", "admin_interface_theme"."css_header_text_color", "admin_interface_theme"."css_header_link_color", "admin_interface_theme"."css_header_link_hover_color", "admin_interface_theme"."css_module_background_color", "admin_interface_theme"."css_module_text_color", "admin_interface_theme"."css_module_link_color", "admin_interface_theme"."css_module_link_hover_color", "admin_interface_theme"."css_module_rounded_corners", "admin_interface_theme"."css_generic_link_color", "admin_interface_theme"."css_generic_link_hover_color", "admin_interface_theme"."css_save_button_background_color", "admin_interface_theme"."css_save_button_background_hover_color", "admin_interface_theme"."css_save_button_text_color", "admin_interface_theme"."css_delete_button_background_color", "admin_interface_theme"."css_delete_button_background_hover_color", "admin_interface_theme"."css_delete_button_text_color", "admin_interface_theme"."css", "admin_interface_theme"."related_modal_active", "admin_interface_theme"."related_modal_background_color", "admin_interface_theme"."related_modal_background_opacity", "admin_interface_theme"."related_modal_rounded_corners", "admin_interface_theme"."related_modal_close_button_visible", "admin_interface_theme"."list_filter_dropdown", "admin_interface_theme"."list_filter_sticky", "admin_interface_theme"."recent_actions_visible", "admin_interface_theme"."form_submit_sticky", "admin_interface_theme"."form_pagination_sticky" FROM "admin_interface_theme" WHERE "admin_interface_theme"."active"
        Params: ()
        Version: 1.3.6

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 59, in execute
    raise db_exe from e
djongo.database.DatabaseError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 267, in handle
    emit_post_migrate_signal(
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 48, in emit_post_migrate_signal
    models.signals.post_migrate.send(
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 177, in send
    return [
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 178, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/admin_interface/models.py", line 28, in post_migrate_handler
    Theme.get_active_theme()
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/admin_interface/models.py", line 56, in get_active_theme
    objs_active_ls = list(objs_active_qs)
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 269, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1303, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/jack/PycharmProjects/document-generation/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 59, in execute
    raise db_exe from e
django.db.utils.DatabaseError
```

I cannot understand what the error message means. Has anybody else faced this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Remove ENFORCE_SCHEMAS from databses settings.